# Teclado invisible en un login con googleSignIn Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, teclado

En un proyecto, me tocó agregar el login con google... sin embargo me sucede algo raro, al querer escribir la contraseña en el view de google, este no muestra el teclado correctamente, la version con la que fue hecha esta app fue en 3.0, hice actualizaciones a 4.2 para que funcionara con Xcode 11. les paso imágenes, estas las tome desde un dispositivo.

hice un nuevo proyecto "demo" implementando el sdk, pensando que podría ser la version de Xcode o swift o algo que ocurrió al momento de actualizar pero pues funciona correctamente en el proyecto "demo".

si ven la segunda foto se ve el toolbar del teclado pero no muestra las teclas y números, la forma en que pude mostrarlo es ir al controller de registrar y regresar después inicio con google otra vez y ahora si me muestra el teclado.

y les dejo como en el AppDelegate esta configurado que Controller presenta.

```
          private func initialController() {
               let session = SessionManager()
               let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
               if session.isLoggedIn() {
                  let mainNav = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeView")
                  self.window?.rootViewController = mainNav
               } else {
                 let loginNav = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginControllerId")
                 self.window?.rootViewController = loginNav
               }
                 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
          }
```

[image: asi me muestra la notificación para aceptar las condiciones de google lo curiosos que el view de fondo es negro.. cuando en realidad debería transparentar el view donde esta el botón de login dado. que es un present]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

saludos y gracias adelantadas!

Comment: estas probando en un simulador?

Comment: no, sucede tanto en dispositivo como en simulador, las fotos son del dispositivo

Comment: y lo curioso que hice una implementación en un proyecto nuevo y funciona a la perfección, sin embargo no se que problema o que sea lo que este causando ese bug

Answer (score 0):

Bueno como a veces suele suceder yo mismo solucione el problema, simplemente cree otro proyecto reconfigurandolo, colocando todas sus clases y demás como en el proyecto old, pasando a utilizar el sceneDelegate, y por supuesto el AppDelegate en caso de que los dispositivos usen iOS 12.5 o mas antiguos.

nunca di con una solución clara sobre este raro bug, pero se que lo provoco algo cuando se migro de swift 3 luego a 4 y por ultimo a 5.